# SAAB 9-5 wagon throws P1549 Code (Boost control valve)

Tags: cel, power, turbocharger, saab, valve

I called an ASE-certified mechanic. He charged some $60 for the visit and $60 diagnosis and really he didn't quite spot on anything. Left me where I was  - work-wise , diagnosis-wise and  knowledge-wise. So I am reaching out to hopefully a more "pundit" community here.

I was driving up hill and suddenly at 2000 RPM , I got a CEL due to P1549 (Expanded to BOOST CONTROL VALVE).

I checked all the vacuum hoses. They were okay this time too.. they've now been checked a total of three times. And all three occasions were related to excessive power for uphill or whenever I sought extra speed by going beyond 3000 RPM. Typically, it will happen after about 150 miles of  driving. I will clear it and continue to drive.

The turbo bypass valve is actually the forge kind of valve which has 2 rings or washers and a spring in it. The washers do not remain in the center but will fall down towards the inlet for the vacuum hose. I am not sure how they're supposed to be positioned in there and what their presence will make in terms of power.

Why am I getting this error and what should I do to fix it?

BOMK also - the wastegate is built into the turbo. 

This is a SAAB 9-5 5 Speed 2000 2.3t wagon

Comment: Welcome to the site. I've edited your question to make it a bit more readable. Questions for you: 1. You say the CEL appears after 150 miles of driving. Is this 150 miles of driving after resetting the CEL? 2. Could you obtain fuel trim information through an OBD II reader? 3. Pictures of the specific valve part you're trying to describe would be great.

Comment: Yes its after reset. I got it .  That was on long drives. Now I am back in the city and I don't rev up the gas that much - so I have not gotten the code then on BUT the car will suddenly JOLT in 5th or 4th ( only once in  4th )   and looks like it is getting to much Boost that is shutting down the engine..? in the case how do I go about reducing the boost

Comment: @Zaid   Did the OP give you the data you need to answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

P1549 (Trionic 7) is "Charge Air, Malfunction".  (You don't say what year your 9-5 is, but T7 is pretty common.)  Since you checked the vacuum hoses going to the charge-air control valve, then it's "basic engine and turbo" to check; but it seems to work below the critical speed. Then, change the charge-air control valve.  This is not the same thing as your Forge turbo bypass valve, but this thing or its equivalent for your model year, so double-check the fitment:  https://www.esaabparts.com/saab/parts/55557331

If your car is more than about 10 years old, I'd replace that 3-hose assembly that feeds this solenoid valve, as well.  They may look OK but they all rot sooner or later.  Item 17 on this page, with a couple of variants by engine number, so be careful: https://www.esaabparts.com/viewparts.php?searchpart=1&section=311045036